# Updating text file from the python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nltk

Hello Community Members,

Suppose that i am having a dictionary in python:

```
dict = {'fresh air', 'entertainment system', 'ice cream', 'milk', 'dog', 'blood pressure'}
```

and a list of texts like:

```
text_file = ['is vitamin d in milk enough', 'try to improve quality level by automatic intake of fresh air', 'turn on the tv or entertainment system based on that individual preferences', 'blood pressure monitor', 'I buy more ice cream', 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in ice cream']
```

I want to display each occurrence of phrase belong to dictionary (say fresh air) as `#fresh_air#` in all the occurrences of the text file whereas for each single word of the dictionary (say `milk`), the output should display as `#milk#`, i.e. appending special characters at the start and end in all the occurrences of the text_file.

Output which I want should be in the following form (lists of lists):

```
[[is vitamin d in #milk# enough], [try to improve quality level by automatic intake of #fresh_air#], [turn on the tv or #entertainment_system# based on the individual preferences], [#blood_pressure# monitor], [I buy more #ice_cream#], [proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in #ice_cream# with #milk#]]
```

Does there exist any standard way to achieve this in an time-efficient manner?

I am a newbie to lists and text processing using python, I have tried using list comprehension but failed to achieve the desired results. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: you have a `set` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
data = {'fresh air', 'entertainment system', 'ice cream', 'milk', 'dog', 'blood pressure'}
pattern = re.compile("("+"|".join(data)+")")
text_file = ['is vitamin d in milk enough', 'try to improve quality level by automatic intake of fresh air', 'turn on the tv or entertainment system based on that individual preferences', 'blood pressure monitor', 'I buy more ice cream', 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in ice cream']

result = [pattern.sub(r"#\1#", i) for i in text_file]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['is vitamin d in #milk# enough',
 'try to improve quality level by automatic intake of #fresh air#',
 'turn on the tv or #entertainment system# based on that individual preferences',
 '#blood pressure# monitor',
 'I buy more #ice cream#',
 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in #ice cream#']
```

**Note** your `dict` variable is a `set` object.

---

*Updated snippet as requested in comment.*

**Demo:**

```
import re
data = {'fresh air', 'entertainment system', 'ice cream', 'milk', 'dog', 'blood pressure'}
data = {i: i.replace(" ", "_") for i in data}
#pattern = re.compile("("+"|".join(data)+")")
pattern = re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(data)+r")\b")
text_file = ['is vitamin d in milk enough', 'try to improve quality level by automatic intake of fresh air', 'turn on the tv or entertainment system based on that individual preferences', 'blood pressure monitor', 'I buy more ice cream', 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in ice cream']

result = [pattern.sub(lambda x: "#{}#".format(data[x.group()]), i) for i in text_file]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['is vitamin d in #milk# enough',
 'try to improve quality level by automatic intake of #fresh_air#',
 'turn on the tv or #entertainment_system# based on that individual preferences',
 '#blood_pressure# monitor',
 'I buy more #ice_cream#',
 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in #ice_cream#']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh for the help. I will go through your suggested code in detail.

Comment: Also, bad idea to use a builtin name (`dict`) as a variable name.

Comment: @Rakesh. Thanks. How to append special characters (like `#fresh_air#`) in the phrases by preserving the same structure as mentioned in your suggestion?

Comment: @MishraS. Updated snippet

Comment: I was trying in betwen with `data = [w.replace(' ', '-') for w in data]`. Thanks a ton, rakesh. It helps

Comment: Could you please elaborate the use of group along with lambda filter?

Comment: @Rakesh. Suppose that I have included the word (car) in the data (dictionary) and update the text file 1st sentence as `['is vitamin d in milk enough carrying',...]`. From your suggestion, the output what I am getting is something strange. From your suggestion, I am getting the output as `['is vitamin d in #milk# enough #car#rying', ...]`. How to display the output as only ['is vitamin d in #milk# enough carrying',...]. Please suggest something.

Comment: @MishraS. You need to use regex boundaries. Use: `pattern = re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(data)+r")\b")` in the above solution